# Using OPC_UA in ROS Noetic to communicate with PLCs?

Tags: ros-noetic, communication, plc

I am trying to find a package for using opc_ua with ROS Noetic, but I could only find it for Indigo and Kinetic. So is it possible to use opc_ua with ROS Noetic? If not, what other options do I have to communicate with S7-1200 PLC?

Comment: You still seem to have your two accounts, [1](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/users/40012/samy) and [2](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/users/39994/samy). Are you having trouble [merging the two accounts](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts)..?

Answer (score 0):

There is an open issue, [Add noetic build #23](https://github.com/iirob/ros_opcua_communication/pull/23), and an [awaiting commit](https://github.com/iirob/ros_opcua_communication/pull/23/files) to `ci.yml`

```yaml
env:
          - {ROS_DISTRO: kinetic, ROS_REPO: main, ADDITIONAL_DEBS: "libmbedtls-dev"}
          - {ROS_DISTRO: melodic, ROS_REPO: main, ADDITIONAL_DEBS: "libmbedtls-dev"}
          - {ROS_DISTRO: noetic, ROS_REPO: main, ADDITIONAL_DEBS: "libmbedtls-dev"}
```